# Новичек в Yii. При изменения файлов вылез ошибка

Tags: php, yii2, yii

На что ругается Yii2?

Я забыл что изменил и перестал работать сайт.

> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
>   Getting unknown property: common\models\Articles::id

```
if (method_exists($this, 'set' . $name)) {
            throw new InvalidCallException('Getting write-only property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
        } else {
            **throw new UnknownPropertyException('Getting unknown property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);**
        }
```

Comment: Посмотрите лог и diff последних изменений.

Comment: Getting unknown property: common\models\Articles::id
Смотрите, что не так с id в модели Articles

Comment: вы где то вызываете $model->id, а его не существует.